# "Command \Ref already defined" after updating latex

Tags: macros

Today I updated ubuntu eoan to focal, and with it texlive got updated, too. After the update, while trying to recompile a huge book using dozens of packages, I got

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \Ref already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.952 \newcommand*{\Ref}{\keyword{ref}}

?
```

I know that my work defines `\Ref` this way. Who else defines `\Ref`? I thought that internal macroses of other packages should contain `@` in them to avoid clashes with user-defined macroses. Or is `\Ref` in the public interface of some package now?

Comment: Well you are the one who knows which packages your code loads.

Comment: you only need to add \show\Ref in suitable places.

Comment: @Just_A_Man That would be a good start.

Comment: In all places that would help you to identify the package which defines the command.

Comment: But as of kernel updates in 2019 I think `\Ref` (formerly part of `fncylab` ) is now part of the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: `\Bbbk` is defined in `amssymb` at least, and that's font related, so you know that any other definition would be in a font-related package.  When the problem with `\Ref` was reported, did you kill the job immediately, or let it continue?  That report would have still been in the preamble, so if you let the job continue until it gets into the actual processing of the body, you can probably identify most of the package-conflict problems at once.

Comment: The usual recommendation for such a conflict is to add `\let\Bbbk\relax` after loading `newtxmath` and before loading `amssymb`.  (I really don't know what else might be defined by both `newtxmath` and `amsfonts`/`amssymb`.)

Comment: Was `newtxmath` added recently?  This loads Times fonts for math, and the shapes are somewhat different from the default Computer Modern.  (However, Times symbols are usually narrower than CM, so an increase in number of pages is unexpected.)   A puzzlement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\Ref` command, formerly part of the `fncylab` package, has now been incorporated into the LaTeX kernel. It is designed to provide a capitalized label format for references at the beginning of a sentence. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\labelformat{section}{section #1}
\begin{document}
\section{\label{foo}}
This is a normal reference to \ref{foo}. 
\Ref{foo} is referred to at the beginning of a sentence and is therefore capitalized.
\end{document}
```